# RetriesExhaustedError on connecting to HPE iLO 5 through Python iLO REST client

Tags: python, rest

Following is a Python based RESTful library client (recommended by HP https://developer.hpe.com/platform/ilo-restful-api/home) that uses Redfish REST API (https://github.com/HewlettPackard/python-ilorest-library) to connect to the remote HPE iLO5 server of ProLiant DL360 Gen10 based hardware

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import redfish

iLO_host = "https://xx.xx.xx.xx"
username = "admin"
password = "xxxxxx"

# Create a REST object
REST_OBJ = redfish.redfish_client(base_url=iLO_host,username=username, password=password, default_prefix='/redfish/v1')

# Login into the server and create a session
REST_OBJ.login(auth="session")

# HTTP GET request
response = REST_OBJ.get("/redfish/v1/systems/1", None)

print response

REST_OBJ.logout()
```

I am getting **RetriesExhaustedError** when creating REST object. However, I can successfully do SSH to the server from the VM (RHEL7.4) where I am running this script. The authentication details are given correctly. I verified that the Web  Server is enabled (both port 443 and 80) in the iLO Security - Access settings. Also, in my VM box the Firewalld service has been stopped and IPTables is flushed. But still connection could not be established. What other possibilities I can try yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause. The issue is with SSL Certificate verification being done by the Python code. 
This can be turned off by setting the environment variable **PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0** before running the code solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old topic, but perhaps for other people that have a similar issue when accessing the iLO in any way, and not just over Python:

You most likely need to update the firmware in your server, so that the TLS is updated. You will most likely need to use an old browser to do this, as modern versions of Mozilla/Chrome will not work with old TLS. I have had luck with Konqueror.